# Get only french datasets on data.europa with sparql

Tags: sparql, sparqlwrapper, geosparql

Is there a way to get dataset only for french country?
The request below response's is for all europe data set.

```
url = "https://data.europa.eu/sparql"

PREFIX dcat: <http://www.w3.org/ns/dcat#>
PREFIX odp: <http://data.europa.eu/euodp/ontologies/ec-odp#>
PREFIX dct: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dqv: <http://www.w3.org/ns/dqv#>
PREFIX piveau: <https://piveau.eu/ns/voc#>

SELECT ?dataset ?datasetURI ?y WHERE {
?dataset dqv:hasQualityMeasurement ?x .
?datasetURI a dcat:Dataset .
?x dqv:isMeasurementOf piveau:scoring .
?x dqv:value ?y
}
```

Comment: you should be able to get datasets for France with: `PREFIX dcat: <http://www.w3.org/ns/dcat#>
PREFIX vcard: <http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?dataset WHERE {
?dataset a dcat:Dataset .
?dataset dcat:contactPoint/vcard:hasAddress/vcard:country-name "France"
}`